# How to scan ibeacons using cordova-plugin-ibeacon?

Tags: android, cordova, ibeacon, hybrid-mobile-app

I am using [petermetz/cordova-plugin-ibeacon](https://github.com/petermetz/cordova-plugin-ibeacon) in my hybrid application, plan to deploy it on Android devices only.

I have seen application that detect beacons placed nearby, and i want to achieve same functionality but using cordova plugin in my hybrid app.

Can some one help in detecting ibeacons present nearby with their details like their UUID as the sample given doesn't explains much about scanning.

Thanks,
Rohit

Answer (score 1):

Simply follow the example on the README of the page linked in the question for "Start ranging a single iBeacon", and replace the major and minor field values with null.  This will scan for all beacons with the UUID specified.

It is not possible to use the plugin to scan for all beacons regardless of UUID because iOS does not allow this.

Comment: What if I do not know about the uuid beforehand? I walk into a room and I want to find all the iBeacons.

Comment: Again, iOS APIs do not allow this.  It is simply not possible to do this on iOS devices with public APIs.